# How can I get the value from a series of textbox with same id

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a series of textboxes with the same name

```
<%for(i=0;i<=nooftasks;i++){%>
<input type="text" id="duration"
name="duration" class="td4" onkeyup="durationFormat()">
}%>
```

In Javascript I have to add a colon after two digits

```
function durationFormat()
{
    var duration = document.getElementsByName("duration").value;
    if(duration.length==2){
        duration=duration+":";
    }
}
```

But I could not get the desired result as I could not get the string from the `textbox` of that particular text box.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, first idea is that you are using same `id` for different properties and that will give you a couple of errors. First, change that.

Comment: I think this might be typo but you misspelled `length`

Comment: Multiple elements with the same `name` is fine, but `id` should be unique or omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <input type="text" id="duration" name="duration" class="td4" onkeyup="durationFormat(this)">
<script>
 function durationFormat(obj) {
     if ((obj.value.length)== 2) {
         obj.value+=":";
     }

 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByName` returns a NodeList not an Element. A NodeList is like an Array. You need to loop over it and apply your changes to each value in turn.

Even if you have used `getElementById`(which returns an Element) and had unique IDs for your inputs (you don't, this is invalid, fix it) then it still wouldn't modify the value. Copying the `value` property into a variable and then modifying it won't change the `value` property of the input. You would need to go back and then `input.value = duration` after you made your modification.

---

If you want to get the specific input that invoked the function, then:

1. stop using intrinsic event attributes. They are a pain
2. use `addEventListener` instead
3. use event delegation to simplify the attaching of the handler
4. examine the target property to determine which input was invoked

such:

```
<fieldset id="durations">
<legend>Durations</legend>
<%for(i=0;i<=nooftasks;i++){%>
<input type="text" name="duration" class="td4">
}%>
</fieldset>

<script>
    function durationFormat(ev) {
        var input = ev.target;
        if (input.value.length === 2) { 
            input.value += ":";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('durations').addEventListener('keyup', durationFormat);
</script>
```

Comment: even though if i use document.getElementById i am unable to get the value of that specific textbox which invoked the function

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, ok if there is any other ways do get the value of that specific textbox(without changing the id of the textbox)

Comment: can you please specify waht does the parameter ev here how it got assigned

Comment: It's an [event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event). See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop into your elements with name `duration`.

```
function durationFormat() {
    var duration = document.getElementsByName("duration");

    for (var i = 0; i < duration.length; i++) {
        if(duration[i].value == 2){
            duration[i].value += ":";
        }
    }
}
```

The logic for this is:

- Firstly, get all `elements` that have an attribute name with `duration` value in that property.
- Secondly, you have to loop inside the array of elements you got when called `.getElementsByName` method.
- To finish, you have to set the value of each element with a `:` at the end of the value if his value is `2`.

For those that don't understand what `duration[i].value += ":";` does, automatically gets the value of the input element at `i` position of the array and adds the value `:` at the end. It's exactly the same that if you do `duration[i].value = duration[i].value + ":";`. I prefer to use `+=`, because it's sorter. I never tested, but I think that it's also the fastest way for browsers to add some content at the end. It can also be used for string variables.

Comment: Please also explain your logic, as per `stackoverflow` recommendation